# How to route user generated paths in cakephp eg mysite.com/username1?

Tags: cakephp

I'm making a cakephp 2.3 app and have these "pages":

```
mysite.com/demo
mysite.com/admin
```

The above are fixed.  The below are generated:

```
mysite.com/johnsmith
mysite.com/cooluser88
```

I've updated the routes with:

```
Router::connect(
'/*/',
array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'redirect')
```

);

Am I on the right track? a redirect method in the pages controller? I'm using the official docs but I haven't been able to find specific examples.

I'll keep working on it and will update with an answer if I find one!

Comment: Not exactly. How should the router know which ones are the username routes and which aren't. You could try to put this rule at the end. But I still recommend using a more distinct namespace here.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking in the redirect method pickup the base string '/*/' and check if it is one of the fixed ones or in the user database? And yes I was thinking of putting this at the end after the fixed routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet IMO is to do something like reddit where each slug is prefixed with `/r/`.

Example:

```
mysite.com/u/johnsmith
```

Then, in your routes, you can do something like this:

```
Router::connect('/u/:uname/*', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'display'), 
    array('pass'=>array('uname')));
```

If you really don't want to do that, you can use something like:

```
Router::connect('/:uname/*', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'display'), 
    array('pass'=>array('uname')));
```

But keep in mind, any other controllers, plugins...etc etc etc will need their own routes, since it will think that ANYTHING passed after the `mysite.com/` is a `uname`.  Not the best idea IMO.